# How can I check if an instance of a subtring is at the end of a string and just once (say using strstr)?

Tags: c, linux, string, shell, strstr

I want to check if user is entering something like `ls&` or `ls &` so that I will be able to set the `bg_flag` for background jobs in the shell. however the following code can't check against `ls&&`. because I don't want it to be considered a background job(I am not sure if it's the same in Linux shell) if user enters `ls&&` or anything with more than one `&` in the end.

```
  if (strstr(args[arg_count-1],"&")!=NULL)
  //if (strcmp(args[arg_count-1],"&")==0)
              {
                bg_flag=1;
                printf("I am a background job %d ",getpid());
              }
```

Please let me know what is the appropriate method for fixing this?

Comment: Maybe something like "strstr(p, "&") && !strstr(p, "&&")" ?

Answer (score 4):

To do that reliably, you need to properly parse the command in the same way the shell does it.  Usually you define a grammar for that and use a parser generator. Everything else is just guessing and will most likely fail.

For example, consider this:

```
some_program \&&
```

it ends with two ampersands (`&&`) but anyway it will be a background process because the first ampersand is escaped (`\&`).

However, marking the postfix `\&&` as "background" is also not correct because

```
some_program \\&&
```

would not be a background process (but an incomplete command instead).

And as long as you don't define a proper grammar, it's very likely that you will not correctly catch everything as my two examples may show.

Another sort of problems might be programs that detach themselves from the terminal (sometimes called daemonization). They are not backgrounded by the shell, they do the same by themselves.

Comment: Are you telling me that Linux shell considers ls&& as nested background jobs?

Comment: Typo: "it ends with two ampersands". +1

Comment: @MonaJalal no, `ls&&` is just an incomplete command. `ls&&echo` would be valid, that would execute `ls` (in the foreground) and if its return code it `0` then it would execute `echo` (in the foreground as well). `ls \&& echo` however would invoke `ls \&` in the background and `echo` in the foreground in parallel.